# Program received signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c

Задание - создание BST-дерева методом вставки в лист(рекурсивная реализация). Рекурсивная функция печати элементов дерева (симметричный обход дерева).
Не могу понять, что не так.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

typedef struct Node{
    int data;

    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

void adding(Node ** cur, int x){

    if((*cur) == NULL){
        (*cur) = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*cur)->data = x;
        (*cur)->left = NULL;
        (*cur)->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if(x >= (*cur)->data){
            adding((*cur)->right, x);
        } else {
            adding((*cur)->left, x);
        }
    }
}

Node *create(int x){
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    Node *head = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i<x; i++){
        adding(head, rand()%100);
    }
    return head;
}

int printing(Node *cur){
/*  if(cur->left != NULL) printing(cur->left);
    printf("%d ", cur->x);
    if(cur->right != NULL) printing(cur->right);*/

    if (cur == NULL) return;
    else{
        printing(cur->left);
        printf("%d ", cur->data);
        printing(cur->right);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("chcp 1251");

    int n;

    printf("Fill in a number ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    Node *Head;
    Head = create(n);
    printing(Head);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Под отладчиком запускать пробовали?

Comment: пробовал, но все равно не понял лол...
как я понял, ломается вот здесь:
  if(x >= cur->data){
но это не точно

Comment: if(cur = NULL)... Либо ==, либо if (cur), но даже если исправить это, то всё равно неправильно будет работать, потому что Node *cur в void adding() локальная переменная и head из Node *create() не меняется, передавайте по двойному указателю Node **cur

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon поменял, но все равно что-то не то

Comment: @arthurasche `adding(&head, rand()%100);` и  `adding(&(*cur)->left, x);` / right

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon заработало, спасибо огромное!!!